# How to convert Pandas Dataframe into Numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, job-scheduling

In my project of Job-Shop Scheduling, I have to schedule fifty jobs and each job has multiple operations that can be executed on five machines. The sample CSV data of the first three jobs are as follow: 
[Sample Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6efzF.png).

I wana convert above dataframe into the following numpy array:

```
jobs_data = [  # task = (MC_ID, BURST_Time).
    [(1, 20), (3, 23), (4, 20), (3, 22)],  # JOB_ID = 0
    [(1, 22)],  # JOB_ID = 1
    [(4, 22)],  # JOB_ID = 2
]
```

I have tried using different functions but failed to get the required results.

Comment: So you have the logic down as written in the question statement, are you simply asking for what the easiest method of data management is?

Comment: Yes right, I am trying to find best possible solution to get jobs_data array from the CSV file by following the constraints or conditions explain in question.

Comment: Ask direct questions and answer questions directly. Make your questions easy to understand. Direct communication is what gets answers on here. You have way too many words. Don't ask multiple questions if you don't need multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas read_csv to read the file.
Then you can convert to a NumPy array.
`pd.read_csv('<filepath>');`

`pd.DataFrame(dataframe).to_numpy()`